# how to send media with meta data (caption, description) via POST request to WordPress REST API with python

Tags: python, wordpress, post, python-requests, request

I am trying to make a POST request to a Wordpress REST API using python-requests. The POST data contains an image and meta data (like title and description). The upload of the image is successful without any problem, but none of the caption, description,... data is included. What am I missing? Here is my code

```
    header = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8'),
              "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"
    }

    media = {
         'file': open("img.jpg","rb"),
         'title': "title",
         'caption': "caption",
         'description': "description",
         'alt_text': "alt_text"
    }

    image =  requests.post(url + '/media' , headers= header, files= media,timeout=15)
```

Comment: What exactly is in your header?

Comment: i did add the header... as this doc https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/#create-a-media-item ...sad "The attachment caption" needed... how can i set that... and tnx for editing my post ..my EN is not good @buddemat

Comment: My mistake. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have to make two requests, the first to upload the image, and a second to set the caption and description. The following code should work for you (taken largely from [1]):

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8')} 

media = {'file': open('img.jpg','rb')}

# first request uploading the image
image = requests.post(url + '/media', headers=headers, files=media) 

# get post-id out of the response to the first request
postid =json.loads(image.content.decode('utf-8'))['id'] 

# set the meta data
post = {'title': 'title',
        'caption': 'caption',
        'description': 'description',
        'alt_text': 'alt_text'
       }

# second request to send the meta data
req = requests.post(url + '/media/'+str(postid), headers=headers, json=post)
```

[1] https://github.com/timsamart/wp_upload_media